# What do you call someone who is very careful with their word choice?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who knows the exact denotation of many words and uses very specific words to describe something?

I remember reading a sentence that went like this: 
Only a _____ knows the meaning of _____.  (where ____ is the word I'm looking for)

Comment: *Grandiloquent*? *Magniloquent*?

Comment: Perhaps a **pedant** (some of its senses anyway)?

Comment: Yes, the sentence begs a perjorative word.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, that was the word I was looking for. I had somewhat misunderstood the meaning of pedant, so thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I was looking for another word, but thanks for those words anyways. I had no idea there were so many fancy words for those with an affinity for language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **lexicographer**? From Lexico:

> **[lexicographer](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lexicographer)**: A person who compiles dictionaries.

Your example:

> Only a **lexicographer** would know the meaning of X.

Another possibility is **vocabularian**. From Wiktionary:

> **[vocabularian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vocabularian)**: One who cultivates a large vocabulary.

Your example:

> Only a **vocabularian** would know the meaning of X.

Answer (score 0):

How about *wordsmith*?

> Only a *wordsmith* knows the meaning of _____.
>
> **Wordsmith (noun):** A person skilled in using words.

[**[Collins Concise English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wordsmith)**]

Answer (score 0):

From comments under the question, a word that is of the same type as what is being looked for is [**pedant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : one who is unimaginative or who unduly emphasizes minutiae in the presentation or use of knowledge
>   **1 b** : one who makes a show of knowledge
>   **1 c** : a formalist or precisionist in teaching